# How can i load a table view in a container view(another sence)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, view, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to change the container view when the index of segmented control is change. I try to set/change the container before:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ResMainViewController *newVC = [[ResMainViewController alloc]initWithClassName:@"ResMainViewController"];
    [self addChildViewController:newVC];

    // Add the new view controller view to the ciew hierarchy
    [self.containerView addSubview:newVC.view];

    // End the view controller transition
    [newVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    // Store a reference to the current controller
    self.containerView = newVC.view;
}
```

However,it is not work. I can receive the log from tableView but there is nothing inside the tableview(cell). Did i miss nothing? Please Help!!!

Comment: newVC.view.bounds = self.containerView; // before addSubview and also check that delegate methods of tableview are getting called or not, and array which u passing in tableview is not nil.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the segmented control function?

Comment: The segmented control is for showing different table views in the container view.

Comment: I try to put the table view in the container view , but it said that 'reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "t1e-dE-M9M-view-bbb-R6-hPv" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'